# What is the difference between padding-left and padding-start?

Tags: html, css, webkit, mozilla

While inspecting some code I found this new declaration: `-webkit-padding-start` but I am been unable to understand what is the difference with the existing `padding-left` property.
I have already read the page on [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-padding-start) and created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrMw/1/), but I am still unsure.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/avrMw/3/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apart from `-webkit-padding-start` being nonstandard, the difference is that when writing direction is right to left, `-webkit-padding-start` puts padding to the right (effectively, gets converted to `padding-right`).

If the property were standardized, it would be useful for style sheets that are meant to be used for documents containing texts in different writing systems. You could then put padding at the start of text, provided that you have set the `dir` attribute in HTML or the `direction` property in CSS properly to correspond the directionality. So the padding would be on the left of the start of text e.g. in Western languages but to the right of the start of the text (which runs from right to left) e.g. in Arabic, Persian, or Hebrew texts.

Answer (score 5):

> If the writing direction is left-to-right, `-webkit-padding-start overrides padding-left`.  If the writing direction is right-to-left,
>   `-webkit-padding-start overrides padding-right`.

<sup>source:[CSS-Info](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-padding-start)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If the computed direction is left-to-right `ltr` then `-moz-padding-start` sets the `left-padding:;` otherwise it sets the `right-padding:;`.

So for example:

**HTML:**

```
<p><a class="left">padding-start: 20px (ltr)</a>
</p>
<p><a class="right">padding-start: 20px (rtl)</a>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .left {
        direction: ltr;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        -moz-padding-start : 20px;
        -webkit-padding-start : 20px;
    }
    .right {
        direction: rtl;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        -moz-padding-start : 20px;
        -webkit-padding-start : 20px;
    }
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/a2qk8/)